# Does installing npm react react-dom in create react app is necessary?

Tags: reactjs, npm, reactstrap

I read the documentation of [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/), and it guide us to install npm package as below;

```
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom
```

my question is, is it necessary to install react and react-dom, aren't those two packages are included by default in create-react-app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! it is included in node_modules by default when you use

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

but you may also choose not to use it for some reason. Then you will need to install them and add your project starting files by yourself.

Comment: thx for the answer, do you know why reactstrap suggested to install it again in it's documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's installed by default when you are make

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

You alse can instal it with typescript if you want via

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

and it will also add @types/react-dom

Comment: thx for the answer, do you know why reactstrap suggested to install it again in it's documentation?

Comment: because that libs in peer dependecy in reactstrap